# Restkit routes conflicting

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am using Restkit to make my requests in my iOS project. My issue is that one of routes is overwriting another route or rather taking precedence.

```
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Prescription class]
                                                    pathPattern:@"v1/prescriptions/:prescriptionID\\.json" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

When I try to call the route below its returning and being mapped as Prescription (the route/mapping above).

```
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[PrescriptionStatus class]
                                                    pathPattern:@"v1/prescriptions/request.json" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

So I am guessing that RestKit thinks "request.json" (aka PrescriptionStatus) is actually me calling for a specific prescription record as if I was calling with "123.json".

How can I setup both these routes and have them both work. Meaning how can I setup both routes above and have call to PrescriptionStatus ("request.json") return a PrescriptionStatus class and map it correctly.  But, also make a call for a specific Prescription ("123.json"), which should return a Prescription.

Answer (score 0):

Which routing are you setting first? I ran into the same issue today, and while looking through RestKit's upgrade documentation I noticed something that solved my issue. If you look at their docs [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0#adding-routes-to-an-object-managers-route-set) and the section below it you will see that they do the routing and mapping on the variable path first. I also setup the mapping and request/response descriptors before the routing, I don't know if that matters but it has been working for me.